# How to write __init__.py (and perhaps __main__.py) file to avoid import ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, import

I thought I had understood the import system, however I'm struggling to understand an apparently trivial case: I have a very simple Python application with the following structure:

```
.
└── myapp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── lib.py
    └── myapp.py
```

The content of **lib.py** is a trivial function:

```
def funct():
    print("hello from function in lib")
```

**myapp.py** is supposed to be the entrance point of the application:

```
import lib  

def main():
    lib.funct()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("calling main")
    main()
```

When I run the main script it works:

```
> python myapp/myapp.py
calling main
hello from function in lib
```

However, when I just import the package from IPython for instance, it fails:

```
In [2]: import myapp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-cabddf3cb27d> in <module>
----> 1 import myapp

~/test/myapp/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 import myapp.myapp

~/test/myapp/myapp.py in <module>
----> 1 import lib
      2 
      3 
      4 def main():
      5     lib.funct()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

Why is this happening? Eventually, I'd like that my application is executable with `python -m myapp`, but also importable.

Comment: When you run `python myapp/myapp.py`, the directory `myapp` is implicitly added to `sys.path`. When you run `ipython`, it isn't.

Comment: Your code, though, does not match the error being raised. Where did `import myapp.myapp` come from?

Comment: I see. Then how do I tell Python where is this module? Do I have to change __init__ using relative imports? Or do I have to change the modules as well? Perhaps yo may want to elaborate in a proper answer…

Comment: Is there anything else in `__init__.py` besides `import myapp.myapp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `import` searches for module on the **paths** present in **sys.path** and one of the path present there is of current directory so
when you executed the main script:

```
python myapp/myapp.py
```

The `import` in myapp.py file searched for **`lib`** module in its current directory i.e "myapp" and as ***lib.py*** is in same directory, it executed perfectly

But when you imported **myapp** as a package in IPython,
The `import` in myapp.py file searches from **IPython's** path, where ***Lib.py*** is not present hence the classic `no module found`.

There are few things you can do here

1. use relevant path in `myapp.py` like

   `from . import lib`
   Note: This will generate error if you executed ***myapp.py*** directly as a script so handle accordingly
2. update the sys.path by appending ***lib.py***'s path **(Not Recommended)**

   `sys.path.append("....../lib.py")`

[watch this](https://realpython.com/lessons/module-search-path/) for clear understanding.

Also just to point out, ***__name__=="__main__"*** is only true when you execute the file directly. so the code inside `if` in ***myapp.py*** will not work when you'll use it as a module in package.

I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks! It’s clearer now. One more thing, if you can expand. Your solution involves relative imports. How can this get solved with absolute imports? Do I necessarily have to use __init__.py?

Comment: init.py is what gives `myapp` folder the power to become a package so if you want to use it as a package, it is required even if you keep it empty. Now if you want to use absolute path you can go with the second approach involving **sys.path**. this will unable you to use `import` directly but with a cost that your **sys.path** list will now contain a path that is specific to this project and not other which is not a good practice but will get the job done.